# SQL Server split sting based on patterns

Tags: sql-server, string, function, design-patterns, split

I'm trying to split a specific string based on two patterns for the first an last character, the first character must be any numeric value and the last is a comma.

I'm using the `patindex`, `substring` and `charindex` functions but they only give a single row.

This is the query that I am working on:

```
DECLARE @x varchar(max) = 'In the vocational certificate category, if served as laundry/dry cleaning specialist, 2 semester hours in treatment of fabrics (stain removing, spotting, solutions), 2 in laundry equipment operation, 2 in dry cleaning, 3 in small business management, 3 in introduction to business, 3 in supply management, and 3 in business report writing.'
   Declare @extract varchar(max) = ''
   set @extract = substring(@x, patindex('%[0-99] [i]%[,] %', @x), (LEN(@x)) -  CHARINDEX('%[0-99] [i]%[,] %', REVERSE(@x))) 
   select @extract
```

The result is this: 
2 in laundry equipment operation, 2 in dry cleaning, 3 in small business management, 3 in introduction to business, 3 in supply management, and 3 in business report writing.

Is there any way to get the results in columns? Like this:

- 2 in laundry equipment operation
- 2 in dry cleaning
- 3 in small business management

...

Comment: SQL Server is not your friend to do this. I don't even understand the logic, if I'm honest, however, if you need to store distinct values, do so *before* you `INSERT` it. If you really need to parse these strings into something else, you'll probably be better off using some kind of CLR function with REGEX support to "split" it.

Comment: And yet you don't want the part about "2 semester hours ...". Seems the first pass is to chop your string up based on a comma separator. Whether that works depends on if the comma can also be elsewhere and NOT interpreted as a separator. Once you have first-level split, you will need to define the logic to ignore the bit I first mentioned. Maybe that can be done positionally?

Comment: Thank you guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree that sql server is the wrong tool for the job it is feasible. You can use the DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD function which can be found here. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2

Then it is rather trivial to deal with this. Please note this does NOT return "3 in business report writing" because that does not follow your rule that the "last value is a comma".

```
DECLARE @x varchar(1000) = 'In the vocational certificate category, if served as laundry/dry cleaning specialist, 2 semester hours in treatment of fabrics (stain removing, spotting, solutions), 2 in laundry equipment operation, 2 in dry cleaning, 3 in small business management, 3 in introduction to business, 3 in supply management, and 3 in business report writing.'

select MyResult = ltrim(s.Item)
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@x, ',') s
where left(ltrim(s.Item), 1) like '%[0-9]%'
order by s.ItemNumber
```

The above query will return.

```
2 semester hours in treatment of fabrics (stain removing
2 in laundry equipment operation
2 in dry cleaning
3 in small business management
3 in introduction to business
3 in supply management
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sean Lange, I really appreciate your help, this is exactly what I needed.